# Exit child activity and return to home activity - what lifecircle is it?

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, lifecycle

[**Warning:** this question contains no code, so may look not interesting.]

An app has the following structure (basically 3 level of activity: home->category->item):

```
--- Home Activity (TabHost)
------- Tab1: category 1 activity, contains item list, 
              onclick item will start "viewItemActivity" to view an item
------- Tab2: category 2 (as above)
------- Tab3: category 3 (as above)
```

When push notification received, on click of the notification message will start viewItem Activity alone. By default, if the users hit "Return" key on their phone, this viewItem Activity will exit and user will be back to phone home screen.

Is there a way to forward user to home activity with corresponding category tab instead of going back to phone home screen?

**A general method/idea would be appreciated.**

I'm unsure of What part of lifecircle/method inside viewItem activity needs to be overwritten. And how to write it to avoid random affects on startup process/stack of the app.

For this overwritten method (onStop!?), I was thinking of checking whether home tab activity is running, if not then start, then pass some intent to display corresponding tab, is this the proper way to do?)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When the notification arrives, you can start the Home Activity and in its onCreate, you can start the itemActivity. That way, in the stack, you will have HomeActivity below item activity and pressing back button will go to Home activity.

Comment: this maybe the proper way to do. I spent whole day implemented this and some other models, but still unsuccessful.

For this model:
on notification receive -> start Home Activity -> Set correct tab for the item category -> Start ViewItem activity.

Problem was that instead of showing the correct tab category, the tab activity starts full screen and out of the tabhost. I believe there're some bugs in TabActivity hence why it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite `onBackPressed()` in each activity and there start your Home activity. To not have your Tab1 activity remaining on the stack, define it to have no History via the MANIFEST file:

```
 <activity android:name=".activity...." android:noHistory="true"></activity>
```